# How to guard on returned mapped value

Tags: typescript

How do I fix the following error without resorting to `any`, explicit casts and guard functions?

```
type T = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
};

const f = <K extends keyof T>(k: K): T[K] => {
    if (k === 'a') {
        /*
        Type '5' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
            Type '5' is not assignable to type 'number & string'.
                Type '5' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        */
        return 5; // error
    } else {
        return '5';
    }
};

// this is equivalent and works, but not always possible/convenient
const g = <K extends keyof T>(k: K): T[K] => {
    return {a: 5, b: '5'}[k];
};
```

Comment: You've really constrained possible answers since you don't want to use type assertions (TS has "assertions", not "casts"), guard functions, or the refactoring at the bottom of your code; I assume you also wouldn't want to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) (which I'd say are morally equivalent to type assertions).  All I can say at this point is that you are highlighting a [known issue filed in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) so I'd expect any progress on this in the future to be reflected there.  Good luck!

Comment: Please, file the reference to the issue as an answer so that I could approve it. I couldn't find the issue for quite a while, and it's the only correct answer we can have right now. Thank you!

Comment: Until/unless that's resolved, though, overloads (although morally equivalent to type assertions) at least contain the problem to only the `f` code, not to all the code *using* `f`. [Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATgNxoYm4DOw5AlngObUC+1KAZgXgDGwZgHs8UXgAoA1rgDkmeQEpchUhWr8hI8ZNkKSKhk1Yc+A4WIm8APAGkoEAB7AIeACb0oMiCFG8sAB8BlD2qlh4IMg06MyBsgjwiIoqMRgZUOQQwATkEgCslFAA9CVO5OSi5LFQnE4ANvTQqJkY2bn5UPIF8tQZnCiDQA)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's not the type of overloading I meant...you want the caller to have a generic function but the implementer to have something concrete, like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeBYAUFKBDAXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4Dc6mpeAzsBQJb4DmNaAvl+gGaF8AY2AsA9vij8APAGkoEAB7AI+ACYMoAawghx-WAD4AFNrxyAlHhgBtOQF0ugkWMnSzeXfsMxrsW28DWAdkWigWQzMEeEQAIiw4yzCMTCgKCGBCCikAVi5MbkUAGwZoVFTMDKycqDjcuIKobnQWtCA).

Comment: @jcalz - I have so much to learn about TS. :-) Took me several minutes to figure out why that worked...if I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is filed as a suggestion in GitHub: [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)

The problem is that control flow analysis (checking `k === 'a'`) only narrows the types of *values* (that is, `k` can possibly be narrowed from `keyof T` to `"a"`); it does not narrow the types of *associated generic type parameters*... so the type `K extends keyof T` is never narrowed in control flow analysis to something like `K extends "a"`.  Such narrowing is not, in general, type safe... since of course you could have two variables of type `K`, and narrowing one of them does not necessarily mean the other is narrowed... especially because `T extends "x" | "y"` does not mean that `T` must be *just one of* `"x"` or `"y"`... it might just be `"x" | "y"` itself.  And there's [no way to say that "just one of" concept](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808).

In the issue, it is [mentioned](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995#issuecomment-363265172) that the fixes they can think of for this would have significant compiler performance implications, and that the issue is in the state of "awaiting more feedback"... that means if you want to see this happen you might want to go to that issue and give it a  or detail your use case if it's more compelling than what's already in there.

The workarounds for this are more or less the ones you stated: [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and refactoring so as to perform an actual index access.  The one not mentioned is using a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), but this is essentially the same as asserting the return value:

```
function f<K extends keyof T>(k: K): T[K]; // call signature same
function f(k: keyof T): T[keyof T] { // impl signature looser
  if (k === "a") {
    return 5;
  } else {
    return "5";
  }
}
```

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeBYAUFKBDAXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4Dc6mpeAzsBQJb4DmNaAvl+gGaF8AY2AsA9vij8APAGkoEAB7AI+ACYMoAawghx-WAD4AFNrxyAlHhgBtOQF0ugkWMnSzeXfsMxrsW28DWAdkWigWQzMEeEQAIiw4yzCMTCgKCGBCCikAVi5MbkUAGwZoVFTMDKycqDjcuIKobnQWtCA)

---